# How do you find all Object Style Overrides in a InDesign Document

Tags: javascript, scripting, adobe, adobe-indesign, overriding

I have several large documents that make extensive use of Object Styles.  The styles have been overridden in places.  I do not want to clear the overrides without seeing them first.  How can I see all of the object style overrides in a document?  Is there a way to do this without going thru every InDesign object by hand?  Maybe some Javascript? A find and replace routine would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

There may be a few options you could explore. 
All which are available with a simple Google search.

1. Displays overridden styles with a strikethrough:
     http://www.indiscripts.com/post/2010/05/show-local-formatting-in-indesign-cs4
     http://in-tools.com/article/scripts-blog/showing-text-formatting-overrides/
2. `Pargraph.styleOverridden (Read Only)`
   `Data Type: boolean`
   *If true, the applied style has been overridden with addtional attributes*:
     https://forums.adobe.com/thread/591217
3. InDesign ExtendedAPI:
     http://yearbook.github.io/esdocs/#/InDesign/

I have created (for my own needs) a little JS script that loops through all Stories and Paragraphs to find Overrides; maybe it helps you in some way:

```
for (s = 0; s < app.documents[0].stories.length; s++) {          
    var myStory = app.activeDocument.stories[s]; 
    for (p = 0; p < myStory.paragraphs.length; p++) { 
        var myParagraph = myStory.paragraphs[p];
        if(myParagraph.styleOverridden == true){
            alert("This Paragraph has overrides!");
            // Do whatever you want to do, e.g. highlight the paragraph...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The object styles (or any other styles in InDesign) do not expose the list of overrides through scripting. It does let you know if the style has local overrides values but does not tell what attributes are overridden.
This is a lengthy work to find the overrides. First, find all the attribute values from the object and then find all the values from the style. If the corresponding values differ, the style has that value overridden for the object we are considering.

Answer (score 0):

I had wrote a script to detect object style overrides. Also see original [discussion here](https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/how-to-find-whether-my-textframe-have-overriddenobjectstyle-or-not-in-my-document-using-javascript/m-p/13071120#M484310). It's an unsophisticated approach, and works by exporting the item as a snippet before and after clearing object style overrides and comparing the xml as text.

```
/**
 * Selects any page items on active spread
 * that have object style overrides.
 * @author m1b
 * @discussion https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/how-to-find-whether-my-textframe-have-overriddenobjectstyle-or-not-in-my-document-using-javascript/m-p/13071120
 *
 * Known limitations:
 * 1. this is more strict than Indesign's own
 *    object style overridden criteria, so
 *    sometimes an object may show differences
 *    while not showing the (+) symbol in the
 *    Object Style panel.
 * 2. It does not perform a smart diff of the
 *    item, so if, for example, the override
 *    added a new line to the snippet xml, the
 *    comparer won't understand this and will
 *    mark every line thereafter as different.
 *    In practice this doesn't matter because
 *    they are obviously different.
 * 3. Not tested with real world situations.
 */

function main() {

    var doc = app.activeDocument,
        items = doc.layoutWindows[0].activeSpread.pageItems;

    doc.selection = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

        if (hasObjectStyleOverrides(items[i]))
            items[i].select(SelectionOptions.ADD_TO);

    }



    /**
     * Determines if item has ObjectStyle overrides.
     *
     * @author m1b
     * @version 2022-07-16
     * @discussion https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign-discussions/how-to-find-whether-my-textframe-have-overriddenobjectstyle-or-not-in-my-document-using-javascript/m-p/13071120
     *
     * Note: this function is WAY MORE STRICT
     * than Indesign's normal determination
     * of overridden-ness.
     *
     * @param {PageItem} item - an Indesign page item.
     * @returns {Boolean} - if true, then object has overrides.
     */
    function hasObjectStyleOverrides(item) {

        if (
            item == undefined
            || !item.isValid
            || typeof item.exportFile !== 'function'
        )
            return;

        // make a duplicate item
        dup = item.duplicate();

        var itemSnippet = saveSnippet(dup, 'item.xml');

        // with no objectStyle overrides
        dup.clearObjectStyleOverrides();

        // and make a snippet of that
        dupSnippet = saveSnippet(dup, 'dup.xml');

        // compare the files, line by line
        // and count differences
        var differences = getDifferences(itemSnippet, dupSnippet, 10);

        // clean up
        dup.remove();

        // found any differences?
        return differences > 0;
    }


    /**
     * Compares two text files, line by line,
     * and word by word, and returns number
     * of differences.
     * @author m1b
     * @param {File} file1
     * @param {File} file2
     * @returns {Number}
     */
    function getDifferences(file1, file2, maxDifferences) {

        var differences = 0,
            atEverySpace = /\s+/g;

        // open both files
        file1.open('r');
        file2.open('r');

        while (
            !file1.eof
            && !file2.eof
            && differences <= maxDifferences
        ) {

            // compare, line by line, word by word
            var line1 = file1.readln().split(atEverySpace),
                line2 = file2.readln().split(atEverySpace),
                len = Math.min(line1.length, line2.length);

            // nothing to see after this element starts
            if (line1[1] == '<?xpacket')
                break;

            // compare words
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++)
                if (line1[i] != line2[i])
                    differences++;

        }

        return differences;

    }




    /**
     * Exports item as an Indesign snippet (XML) file.
     * @author m1b
     * @param {PageItem} item - an Indesign page item.
     * @param {String} name - the snippet file name (include extension).
     */
    function saveSnippet(item, name) {

        // put in temp folder
        var snippetFile = File(Folder.temp.fsName + '/' + name);

        // export as indesign snippet
        item.exportFile(ExportFormat.INDESIGN_SNIPPET, snippetFile, false);

        if (snippetFile.exists)
            return snippetFile;

    }



}


app.doScript(main, ScriptLanguage.JAVASCRIPT, undefined, UndoModes.ENTIRE_SCRIPT, 'Select ObjectStyle Overrides');
```